# Configuring Dual Interfaces for for two external IPs on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, sip

I am trying to connect a second ISP connection to my server for our SIP Phones.

`eth0` has our default 25Mb service on **192.168.1.x**, I've configured

`eth1` for the new 6Mb service to be **10.10.1.x**

Both routers are configured pppoe with unique static IPs, I have separate switches, and one Ubuntu 14Lts server with two ethernet ports. Individually either connected works fine, but with both up I can only `ping -I eth[0|1] 8.8.8.8 -c 3` on one interface however there is no problem pinging each router.

If anyone can help me get both Nic up and running and defaulting primary traffic through `eth0` and Just Asterisk/Sip traffic through `eth1` would save my day.

Some informational outputs:

`# cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.10.1.101
#gateway 10.10.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`$ sudo route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         home.Home       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.10.1.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

`$ sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`

```
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

`$ sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup eth1`

```
ifdown: interface eth1 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

`$ ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:11:c8:44  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe11:c844/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2316517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3877952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1881181270 (1.8 GB)  TX bytes:5573716194 (5.5 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:faee0000-faf00000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:11:c8:45  
          inet addr:10.10.1.101  Bcast:10.10.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe11:c845/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:214622 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13988405 (13.9 MB)  TX bytes:890576 (890.5 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fafe0000-fb000000
```

======================**Edit 1:**===========================

Thank you Peter Zhabin for the iproute2 instructions

```
apt-get install iproute2
echo "1 link2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.10.1.101 table link2
ip route add default via 10.10.1.1 dev eth1 table link2
ip rule add from 10.10.1.101/32 table link2
ip rule add to 10.10.1.101/32 table link2
```

Kind of odd the first time I tried `sudo echo "1 link2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables` it responded -bash: /etc/iproute2/rt_tables: Permission denied
but I switched to Root to avoind needing sudo and there were no further complaints.

======================**Edit 2:**===========================

`# ping -I 10.10.1.101 8.8.8.8 -c 3`

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.10.1.101 : 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2014ms
```

======================**Edit 3:**===========================

`# ip rule show`

```
0:      from all lookup local 
32764:  from all to 10.10.1.101 lookup link2 
32765:  from 10.10.1.101 lookup link2 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

`# ip route show`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.1.101 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
```

`# ip route show table link2`

```
default via 10.10.1.1 dev eth1 
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1  scope link  src 10.10.1.101
```

Showing the link2 table has oddly been kind of hit and miss. I don't understand why it doesn't always print.  Good thing is Ping via the IP works although eth1 doesn't. For completion I am also including the full show tables

`# ip route show table all`

```
default via 10.10.1.1 dev eth1  table link2 
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1  table link2  scope link  src 10.10.1.101 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.1.101 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
broadcast 10.10.1.0 dev eth1  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.1.101 
local 10.10.1.101 dev eth1  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.10.1.101 
broadcast 10.10.1.255 dev eth1  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.1.101 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100 
local 192.168.1.100 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.1.100 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100 
broadcast 192.168.122.0 dev virbr0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
local 192.168.122.1 dev virbr0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.122.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.255 dev virbr0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
local ::1 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
local fe80::225:90ff:fe11:c844 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
local fe80::225:90ff:fe11:c845 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0 
ff00::/8 dev eth0  table local  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev eth1  table local  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101
```

`# ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8 -c 3`

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.10.1.101 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.1.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.1.101 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.1.101 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2015ms
pipe 3
```

`# ping -I 10.10.1.101 8.8.8.8 -c 3`

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.10.1.101 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=29.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=29.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=28.8 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.804/29.192/29.433/0.310 ms
```

Comment: See this http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html also search this site for questions about [policy routing](http://serverfault.com/search?q=linux+policy+routing).

Comment: I don't know if it matters much, but `route -n` would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you have to have your return path set correctly for packets inbound through these gateways. This means that if there's a packet coming in through eth1, the response should also go out via eth1 and not through default route.

For it to work, you need iproute2, that would allow you to have multiple routing tables and multiple gateways. First, you should have only **one** gateway address set up under network/interfaces, let's assume it is 192.168.1.100 network, and you want traffic from 10.10.1.101 go out through eth1 via 10.10.1.1 router.

Then the rest is going to be like this (add sudo as needed):

```
apt-get install iproute2
echo "1 link2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.10.1.101 table link2
ip route add default via 10.10.1.1 dev eth1 table link2
ip rule add from 10.10.1.101/32 table link2
ip rule add to 10.10.1.101/32 table link2
```

This will get you running with your return traffic going to the right router, and you'd be also able to ping -I out both interfaces with no issue. The above does create a second routing table (link2), sets default route and scope for it and adds two rules to handle inbound and outbound traffic.

Should your phones connect to this server from outside, that would be sufficient. If they are somewhere inside, please comment with more details regarding your internal network setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks like the right path I need to be on. I've followed like you said and interfaces only has one gateway now. and the iproute2 commands have been run as specified. `ping -I` still only works on one interface, even after a complete reboot.  I have updated the network/interface listed above, please comment if there are any other outputs I can provide

Comment: Could you please try ping -I 10.10.1.101 8.8.8.8 instead of ping -I eth1? There seems to be a difference in how packets are being forwarded in these two cases.

Comment: updated. Even less output from that method. I didn't post the `eth0` test, because it still works correctly .

Comment: Could you please post output of the following: `ip rule show` `ip route show` `ip route show table link2`

Comment: Now if ping -I does work with IP address I see no other problems, as for me ping -I with interface name does not work too, however, everything else works as expected, e.g. traceroute goes the right way depending on source address and services bound to IP on eth1 work as expected.

Comment: Ok, I am very thankful for your help. And it does seem to work while the link2 table is there. But when I sat down this morning, it was not working, I checked and saw that `ip route show table link2` returned nothing. I recreated it, and all is well again.  Any idea as to what would cause that?

Comment: These settings will be gone as soon as you reboot the server or restart the networking. For them to survive the restart, you need to add them to `/etc/network/interfaces` under appropriate `interface eth1 inet` section in a form of `post-up ip rule add ... ` and `post-up ip route add ...` lines containing your rule and route commands that work for you. You could also add `down ip route delete ...` and `down ip rule del ...` commands for an aesthetic effect :).